# Sorting an array of tables

Tags: lua

This may be easier than I'm making it on myself.  I am relatively new to Lua, but experienced in other languages.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
local state = {}
state[1] = {
   show = true,
   changed = true,
   progressType = "static",
   value = 0,
   total = 9,
   name = "nine",
}

state[2] = {
   show = true,
   changed = true,
   progressType = "static",
   value = 0,
   total = 7,
   name = "seven",
}

state[3] = {
   show = true,
   changed = true,
   progressType = "static",
   value = 0,
   total = 8,
   name = "eight",
}

state[4] = {
   show = true,
   changed = true,
   progressType = "static",
   value = 0,
   total = 6,
   name = "six",
}
```

What I need to do is sort each `table[]` entry based on the value of `table.value5`.  I can't find any functions in the docs that expressely say they do more than just a basic `table.sort` so I find myself a bit stuck.  Do I need to manually sort by iterating through and creating a new table with the sorted data?

Comment: Look at `table.sort` options, and use a 'comp' function to define order.  (I'm assuming you want to sort the array part of the list as you can't sort key-value pairs.)

Comment: @tonypdmtr I've updated the example table.  Given that information, I would want the data moved around such that the data from `state[4]` would become first because `state[4].total` is lowest, and the data from `state[1]` would become last because `state[1].total` is highest.  This is because the parent function reading this data needs it ordered by `.total` to be displayed.

Comment: `table.sort(state,function (a,b) return a.total < b.total end)`

Comment: @tonypdmtr Why you give answer as comment? There is no possibility to mark question as answered with proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't find any functions in the docs that expressely say they do more than just a basic table.sort so I find myself a bit stuck.

I might be misunderstanding your issue, but `table.sort` is exactly what you need in this case:

```lua
local state = {}
state[1] = {
   total = 9,
   name = "nine",
}

state[2] = {
   total = 7,
   name = "seven",
}

state[3] = {
   total = 8,
   name = "eight",
}

state[4] = {
   total = 6,
   name = "six",
}

-- Use table.sort with a custom anonymous function
-- to specify how to compare the nested tables.
table.sort(state, function (a, b) 
    return a.total < b.total
end)

for i=1, #state do
  print(i, state[i].name)
end
```

With `table.sort` you can provide an optional custom function, which can be as easy or complicated as you want it to be. In this case (as per your question) it is enough to simply compare the `total` values of your table.

Comment: I understand.  I didn't find anything that expressly showed me that table.sort would iterate through.  Thanks.